# ReactNavigation: Problems with DrawerNavigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a setup where I have a TabNavigator and the screen for one of the tabs is a DrawerNavigation, which in turn has StackNavigators. I have a couple of problems:

- I can swipe from the left to open the drawer and open the StackNavigator screens, but it does not close the drawer when selecting an item. Calling closeDrawer() from the loaded screen does nothing.
- When calling openDrawer() from a child screen I only get a semitransparent dark screen, but the drawer does not show.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the first issue by passing the closeDrawer() method onPress before navigating like so:

onPress={() => {                                        this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer()),                                  this.props.navigation.navigate(item.screen.toString())
}}